# Como carregar formulário salvo no localstorage em uma tabela?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css3

Preciso que um formulário salvo no `localstorage` seja carregado em outra página, dentro de uma tabela, mas não sei exatamente como fazer isso, o máximo que consigo é que seja carregado na mesma página do formulário, mas desse jeito só carrega os últimos dados salvos.

Código usando:

```
function carregarDados() {
    if (localStorage.length > 0) {
        $("#tit_monografia").val(localStorage.getItem("tit_monografia"));
        $("#nome_autor").val(localStorage.getItem("nome_autor"));
        $("#nome_orientador").val(localStorage.getItem("nome_orientador"));
        $("#area").val(localStorage.getItem("area"));
        $("#ano").val(localStorage.getItem("ano"));
        $("#cidade").val(localStorage.getItem("cidade"));
        $("#resumo").val(localStorage.getItem("resumo"));
    } else {
        alert("Nenhum registro encontrado");
    }
}
```

Alguém sabe como posso resolver?

Comment: Podes explicar melhor "carregado em outra página"? tens a certeza que os dados "antigos" estão lá? pela maneira que estás  ler os dados dá-me ideia que estás a escrever por cima de dados. Era bom usares um _namespace_ para a tua aplicação e usar uma array JSON por exemplo para guardar vários valores de cada um desses campos.

Comment: poderia verificar a como se gravar em json, que ai vc poderia adicionar mais de uma informação, e vc trataria o localstorage como uma tabela de dados, vc escreveria da seguinte forma: link de apoio: http://www.devmedia.com.br/trabalhando-com-html5-local-storage-e-json/29045

Answer (score 0):

Faz assim.
Claro depois de entender seu código vai precisar ser ajustado mas a sintaxe é bem simples, pode procurar no MSDN por WebStorage, de prove as duas "ferramentas" a SessionStorage, que armazena só até fechar a sessão e a LocalStorage que armazena até depois de fechada a sessão, só vai limpar se criar esta opção ou dar um clean no cache.
O formulário basico de exemplo que pode ser usado é esse ai Abaixo...

```
// pega o click do botão de submit do formulário
document.body.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(){

   var form = document.body.querySelector("form"),
       data = new FormData(form),
       json = {}; // objeto que irá guardar os dados

   for(var dados of form){

      var typ = document.body.querySelector("[name='"+dados.name+"']").type,
          val = dados.value;

      if(typ == "radio"){
         val = document.body.querySelector("[name='"+dados.name+"']:checked").value;
      }else if(typ == "checkbox"){
         val = document.body.querySelector("[name='"+dados.name+"']").checked;
      }else if(typ == "select-multiple"){

         var mul = [],
             els = document.body.querySelector("[name='"+dados.name+"']").options;
            for(var x=0; x<els.length; x++){
               if(els[x].selected){
               mul.push(els[x].value);
               }
            }
         val = mul;
      }

      json[dados.name] = val;
   }

   localStorage.setItem("formulario", JSON.stringify(json));

});
```

```
// recuperação dos dados guardados no localStorage
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

   var formulario = localStorage.getItem("formulario");

   if(formulario){ // verifico se o localStorage existe

      var form = document.body.querySelector("form");

      formulario = JSON.parse(formulario);

      for(var dados in formulario){

         var tag = document.body.querySelector("[name='"+dados+"']").tagName,
             typ = document.body.querySelector("[name='"+dados+"']").type;

         if(tag.match(/INPUT|SELECT|TEXTAREA/) && !typ.match(/radio|checkbox|select-multiple/)){

            document.body.querySelector("[name='"+dados+"']").value = formulario[dados];

         }else if(typ == "checkbox"){

            document.body.querySelector("[name='"+dados+"']").checked = formulario[dados];

         }else if(typ == "select-multiple"){
            var mul = formulario[dados];

            for(var item of mul){
               document.body.querySelector("[name='"+dados+"'] option[value='"+item+"']").selected = true;
            }

         }else if(typ == "radio"){
            document.body.querySelector("[name='"+dados+"'][value='"+formulario[dados]+"']").checked = true;
         }

      }

   }
});
```